# Is the physical design of the human beings the best possible?

Tags: soft-question

The stature and design of the human body. Is it possible that the best physical structure belongs to a human being? If not.  What are the flaws in it and what improvements could be done?
Is there actually a perfect physical design in terms of strength and agility?

Comment: What do you want to optimise for? If you want sheer strength, elephants easily outperform us. If you want strength/mass, ants do. If you want speed, cheetahs do. If you want acceleration, squids are pretty good. If you want stability, nothing beats being able to dig downwards and leaving half of your body underground.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biological evolution

Comment: Actually humans are rather weak and clumsy animals (refer to Tarzan series :-) , and that's because they are _specialised_ in other areas: they are intelligent, social and communicating, and skillful. That implyes weaker muscles, teeth, bones, but larger brains, more flexible hands and vocal organs. Probably the brain architecture is improved too, though we don't know enough about it yet.

Comment: One famous example of a "non-inteligent design" is the [imperfection of the human eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_the_eye#Evolutionary_baggage). The eye is highly complex and evolved, but could not revert e.g. the evolutionary baggage of being evolved for underwater sight. There will be many examples of this, but a question on human evolutionary baggage should be really directed to Biology SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, your question can't be answered precisely. Here's my reactions, I hope it could help you :

From a biological (evolution) point of view, a creature can be considered as "good" or "bad" only **in a given environment**. It means that there can't be a "best creature", because you will always find environments in which the "best" becomes "weak".

From a physical point of view, you also need to precise the task that you want to evaluate. Strength and agility is very vague. In my opinion, the human body can be outclassed by other species in any precise physical task.

So maybe your question was more about the impression that the human body is the best design when you consider **all** the activities of human beings ? Or a selection of these activities, like in Olympic Games ? In this case, it's not a surprise because :

- that's how evolution works (the design was selected based on the activities necessary to survive, so we're not bad for these activities *in our environment*)
- and because human beings prefer doing things that their body enables them to do (that seems stupid I know, but would you add 'flying' or 'digging' without tools in the Olympic Games ?)

Answer (score 1):

Humans weren't designed, they evolved in a series of small incremental modifications that each at the time imparted a little overall survival advantage.  Such a method results in a effective design, but not necessarily a optimal one.

This process is ongoing, and there are still modifications that could be made that would be advantageous in some circumstances.  Just like deliberate design, the final stucture is a set of tradeoffs, which each tradeoff having been tested and found to be a little better than before.

Mutations continue to happen, so there are significant variations between individuals and new tradeoffs are always being created.  Some are clearly not "good" in our present situation.  I think we'd all rather not be born blind, or with Downes Syndrom, etc.  There are also other tradeoffs that are more subtle.  What is better, dark skin which prevents sunburn and some types of cancers, or light skin which allows for making vitamin D from sunlight?  Both have been tried and found to be more beneficial than the other in different environments.  If humans hadn't formed advanced societies with global travel, northern Europeans and central Africans would probably become different species in another million years or so.  Each would be more optimal for its local environment, but there is no way to say either one is "better" somehow.